# Automatically keeping shared git subtrees in sync

Tags: git, tfs, synchronization, githooks, subtree

On our server we have different git repos for different projects that share some components as sub-**trees**. It is pretty important to me that they remain sub-**trees**, because we do active development in the whole source base and it is important that people have the most easy and convenient workflow possible. That also means, that ideally a simple `git pull` through a gui tool is the way to work. And subtrees are very, very convenient, because they hide the underlaying complexity by allowing everyone to just clone the repo and see all the stuff they need and eventually push to the team git server.

(Then the git server is supposed to push to the component git repos that will eventually end up in TFS)

Now my problem is, how can I automatically keep the components all up-to-date? My idea was to implement a hook on the project repo that would do a `git subtree pull` prior to accepting any push (and potentially complain that the client is out-of-date) and a second hook that would immediately do a `git subtree push` after the push arrived.

Do you have any better ideas? Every input is welcome.

Comment: I am also having this problem git subtree pull and push are a lot of hassle mainly cause you have to do it for each subtree and type out their name and remote, is it not possible to set an upstream for subtrees and pull/push all at the same time?

Comment: after some back and forth, we agreed to change our tfs structure to make the whole local mapping (and thus git-tfs bridge) significantly easier. So now I'm able to use a 1-to-1 git-tfs bridge and so the problem is avoided.